# Unable to load a scene in a playground with XCode 7 beta 3

Tags: xcode, scenekit, xcode7

I'm unable to load a scene in XCode 7 beta 3 playground... although it was working with Xcode 6.4.... is it bug or something as changed ?

ps : SCNScene(named: "ship.dae") returns nil.

In my Resources folder is ship.dae and texture.png (from the SceneKit template), and here is my code :

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import SceneKit
import XCPlayground

var view = SCNView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
var scene = SCNScene(named: "ship.dae")
view.scene = scene

XCPShowView("view", view: view)
```

Comment: I didn't change anything... except loading this playground in Xcode 6.4 and then Xcode 7 beta 3 (just changing the syntax of XCPShowView)... and after several try... it works now... strange...

Comment: correction... I changed something : I converted the dae file to scn file... and it works with ship.scn instead of ship.dae under XCode 7 beta 3

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode 7

```
import XCPlayground    

let view = // your view
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = view
```

In Xcode 8

```
import PlaygroundSupport  

let view = // your view
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```